# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on lauching, random bug 

Tags: iphone

I've nearly finished my first App but i'm getting a weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS that nearly happens all the time.

Here is the trace :

```
#0 0x02adba93 in objc_msgSend
#1 0x07022e00 in ??
#2 0x028bcbcd in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
#3 0x0003999f in -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
#4 0x002e9f84 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#5 0x0310dafa in PurpleEventCallback
#6 0x02961dc4 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#7 0x028c2737 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#8 0x028bf9c3 in __CFRunLoopRun
#9 0x028bf280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#10 0x028bf1a1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#11 0x002e2226 in -[UIApplication _run]
#12 0x002edb58 in UIApplicationMain
#13 0x0000282e in main at main.m:14
```

The weird thing is that some times the App start normally, so i really don't understant what's going on and some help would be great :)

Comment: Looks like a release/autorelease problem. You might have released an object that's also is autoreleased at a later point.

Comment: Is this with NSZombieEnabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've over-released an object, so when the autorelease pool gets cleared, it's an invalid operation.

Debug it with zombies:

- Double-click your executable [executable http://cl.ly/180aaa2cf72e9ce55717/content](http://cl.ly/180aaa2cf72e9ce55717/content)
- Select Arguments and add NSZombieEnabled with value YES
  [zombies! http://cl.ly/70cd173026d600545d3b/content](http://cl.ly/70cd173026d600545d3b/content)

Then run your app again, and check the console — it should tell you what object is being over-released.

Comment: Like i thought. Didn't now that NSZombieEnabled feature, nice one :)

Comment: Well thanks i didn't know this feature, really usefull. Thanks !!