# how to handle runtime errors in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i have already used exception handling..... but it's don't give exception to me.. so please help me.. how to handle run time error.... then my run time error is
 --- Exec_BAD Access----

Comment: Try to run application either on simulator or if you want to run it in device then run with connected to SDK, and when ever you get the  
 Exec-BAD-ACCESS  

try entering "backtrace" on console   

and findout the reason  
and eliminate it.

Comment: i was also tried that... but it's not help for me

Comment: i think there must be accessed something that is already freed

Comment: if i hidden the image view or set the image is nil... than lines got the runt time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try NSZombieEnabled as I described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360437/exc-bad-access-on-lauching-random-bug/3360480#3360480).